# Equivalent to LINQ's Enumerable.First(predicate)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, linq, filter

In C#, we have [`Enumerable.First(predicate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first). Given this JavaScript code:

```
function process() {
  var firstMatch = ['a', 'b', 'c'].filter(function(e) {
    return applyConditions(e);
  }).shift();

  if(!firstMatch) {
    return;
  }

  // do something else
}

function applyConditions(element) {
  var min = 97;
  var max = 122;

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

  return element === String.fromCharCode(random);
}
```

other than `forEach`, using loop, using multiple or operators or implicitly calling `some(predicate)`, is there a smarter way of finding the `firstMatch`? Preferably a JavaScript function (something like `filterFirst(pedicate)`) which short-circuits on first match resembling C#'s `Enumerable.First()` implementation?

FWIW, I am targeting node.js / io.js runtimes.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel, the correct way to do it is to use [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var firstMatch = ['a', 'b', 'c'].find(applyConditions);
```

If you're using a browser that does not support `.find` you can [polyfill it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)

Comment: +1 Yes `.find(predicate)` is exactly what I am looking for in node.js. This is still experimental and the specification status is draft.

Comment: It's not _really_ experimental to be fair :) The draft has settled they're figuring out semantics of other stuff now.

Comment: First in `c#` throws an exception if there wasn't any matching item. So, `find` is equivalent to `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: BTW, find() returns undefined if no item matches the condition.

Comment: As Hamid points out, this is not equivalent to `First`. This is equivalent to `FirstOrDefault`, so while this is helpful to someone that's looking for a similar question, it's not really helpful for this question.

Comment: @claudekennilol I upvoted Hamid's comment but honestly I think the analog here is `First` given how JavaScript and C# are different in how they handle "value not found". In JavaScript when you access a property that doesn't exist `undefined` is returned - this is a bit of a philosophical thing and why when this API was added it was made to behave like `FirstOrDefault` rather than `First`. You can get `First` by adding `?? (() => { throw new Error('not found'); })()` ala "or die(..)` to convert patterns that return `undefined` to patterns that throw when a value is not found.

Answer (score 7):

`LINQ` users call `first` and `firstOrDefault` a lot with no predicate, which is not possible with `find`. So,

```
  first() {
    var firstOrDefault = this.firstOrDefault();
    if(firstOrDefault !== undefined)
      return firstOrDefault;
    else
      throw new Error('No element satisfies the condition in predicate.');
  }

  firstOrDefault() {
    return this.find(o => true);
  }
```

Comment: Or for first truthy value, `this.find(o => o)`.

Comment: The `find( o => o )` idea is useful for my purposes.  I receive an array of records from a database, and that array either is empty or has record objects in it.   So, `recs.find( r => r )` gets me `undefined` if there are no records, and the zeoreth record if there are some.   But, `find( o => o )` would not behave as expected if, for example, the array you used it on was boolean flags and you really want the zeroeth array item.   `[ false, true ].find( o => o )` returns the array item at index 1, not the one at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could emulate this in the case where you want to return the first *truthy* value with `reduce`.

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce(function(prev, curr) { 
    return prev || predicate(curr) && curr; 
}, false);
```

**edit:** made more terse with @BenjaminGruenbaum suggestion

Comment: Dandy! `reduce()` is pretty close with the exception that it invokes the callback for each element of array (as opposed to short-circuit on first match).

Comment: @vulcanraven I don't think it does - it's just really confusing to follow - it can be written as `return prev || predicate(curr) && curr` - also it will fail for falsey array elements (for example finding 0).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum reduce invokes the callback for the full array always, it doesn't short circuit

Comment: @Esailija it invokes the callback but it doesn't check against the predicate.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, to make it less complicated, consider `callback === predicate`. It calls the callback for each element and does not short-circuit. Think about array with huge size, where the size of array matters and the complexity of algorithm depends on input array being sorted. Meaning there are use cases where short-circuiting makes a great impact. What I was exactly looking for is `.find()` which you [described in an answer below].(http://stackoverflow.com/a/28477788/863980). Now waiting for harmony from ECMAScript 6. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create something reusable:
Define a predicate type first

```
declare global {
  type predicate<T> = (arg: T) => boolean;
}
```

Then define the prototype function on array:

```
  if (!Array.prototype.First) {
  Array.prototype.First = function <T>(condition: predicate<T>): T {
    let matchingItems: T[] = this.filter((item: T) => {
      if (condition(item))
        return item;
    });
    if (matchingItems === null || matchingItems === undefined || matchingItems.length === 0) {
      throw Error('Invalid operation. No items found.');
    }
    return matchingItems[0];
  }
}
```

Now you can call the method 'First' on your array and pass in the predicate. Also supported here is any function return a boolean such as your function 'applyConditions'.

Comment: simple but elegant! +1

Answer (score 0):

There are a few packages:
linq.js - LINQ for JavaScript
https://github.com/mihaifm/linq/
npm install linq

> This is a JavaScript implementation of the .NET LINQ library.
>
> It contains all the original .NET methods plus a few additions.
>
> Written in pure JavaScript with no dependencies.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/linq-to-typescript

Implementation of LINQ for TypeScript

```
await from([bing, google, quackQuackGo])
    .asParallel()
    .selectAsync(downloadHtml)
    .select(getTitle)
    .toArray()
```

older  https://www.npmjs.com/package/linq-typescript